# WebService Serialize Request Lost Nullable Property

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I get a wsdl.cs from my service wsdl use wsdl.exe. Then generate the dll by busing CSharpCodeProvider.

Now i use the dll, create a client to call the service, but some nullable int and decimal property was not serialized to the soap message. why?

here is my code.

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
cp.OutputAssembly = dllFileName;
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.XML.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Web.Services.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
CompilerResults result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, csFileName);
```

the property

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("AutoTesting.UI", "1.0.0.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/UnifiedRequest.xsd")]
 public partial class OrderInfo 
{
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<decimal> Amount {
        get {
            return this.amountField;
        }
        set {
            this.amountField = value;
        }
    }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<int> CustomerNumber {
        get {
            return this.customerNumberField;
        }
        set {
            this.customerNumberField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I call the service like this

```
UPGProcess client = new UPGProcess();
UnifiedRequest request111 = new UnifiedRequest()
{
    OrderInfo = new OrderInfo()
    {
        CompanyCode = "1003",
        PayTermsCode = "002",
        Amount = 100.98M,
        ShippingAmount = 0.00M,
        TaxAmount = 0.00M,
        CurrencyCode = "USD",
        OrderNumber = 109913159,
        OrderDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2012-10-24 23:36:45"),
        CustomerNumber = 10000,
        CustomerCreateDate = DateTime.Parse("2007-03-23T06:41:25.197"),
        Email = "peterssenleong@gmail.com",
        IPAddress = "138.54.191.55",
        ShippingMethod = "G",
        PartialAuth = "Y",
        AddressHistory = "330",
        AddressQuality = "Y",
        OrderCount = "15",
        Password = "sd/fds==",
        RedeemedGCAmount = "0.00",
        RedeemedGCQuantity = "0",
        RushOrder = "N",
        SalesChannel = "E33",
        ShipViaCode = "006",
    },
};
var ddd = client.SendRequest(request111);
```

and the soap is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ...>
    <soap:Body>
        <SendRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <unifiedRequest>
                <OrderInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/UnifiedRequest.xsd">
                    <CompanyCode>1003</CompanyCode>
                    <PayTermsCode>002</PayTermsCode>
                    <TransactionID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Email>peterssenleong@gmail.com</Email>
                    <IPAddress>138.54.191.55</IPAddress>
                    <SellerID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ShippingMethod>G</ShippingMethod>
                    <PartialAuth>Y</PartialAuth>
                    <AddressHistory>330</AddressHistory>
                    <AddressQuality>Y</AddressQuality>
                    <OrderCount>15</OrderCount>
                    <Password>sd/fds==</Password>
                    <RedeemedGCAmount>0.00</RedeemedGCAmount>
                    <RedeemedGCQuantity>0</RedeemedGCQuantity>
                    <RushOrder>N</RushOrder>
                    <SalesChannel>E33</SalesChannel>
                    <ShipViaCode>006</ShipViaCode>
                    <MLResult xsi:nil="true" />
                    <DoubleAddress xsi:nil="true" />
                    <HijackAccount xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ShippingCompanyName xsi:nil="true" />
                    <PONumber xsi:nil="true" />
                    <WillCallName xsi:nil="true" />
                    <WillCallPhone xsi:nil="true" />
                    <VmeCardBlockMatch xsi:nil="true" />
                    <GuestCustomer xsi:nil="true" />
                    <VmeRiskAdvice xsi:nil="true" />
                    <GCDeliveryDate xsi:nil="true" />
                    <GCReceiverEmail xsi:nil="true" />
                    <GCReceiverName xsi:nil="true" />
                    <GCSenderName xsi:nil="true" />
                    <BillingQasLevel xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Distance xsi:nil="true" />
                    <IPBillingSameCity xsi:nil="true" />
                    <IPBillingSameState xsi:nil="true" />
                    <IPCity xsi:nil="true" />
                    <IPCountry xsi:nil="true" />
                    <IPState xsi:nil="true" />
                    <IPZipcode xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ShippingQasLevel xsi:nil="true" />
                    <IsResubmitSO xsi:nil="true" />
                    <IsSplitSO xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ShoppingCartID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <RefundType xsi:nil="true" />
                    <NeweggFlash xsi:nil="true" />
                    <HighVolume xsi:nil="true" />
                    <GoogleEmail xsi:nil="true" />
                    <RedeemedEggPoints xsi:nil="true" />
                </OrderInfo>
        </unifiedRequest>
    </SendRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

***you can see the CustomerNumber is missing. Somebody can help me?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my issue.

That's because this is a CustomerNumberSpecified Property in OrderInfo class, by default it's false, so the CustomerNumber will not be Serialized.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool CustomerNumberSpecified
```

Every time I set value for CustomerNumber I set true for CustomerNumberSpecified, all work well.